# Automatic scaling of tikz images in floatrow

Tags: subfloats, floatrow

I have multiple images in a row (using floatrow) and would like to scale them, that they fill the row, while their top and bottom edges are flush to each other, and the aspect ratio of the images them self is kept. Note that I have arbitray aspect ratios. Poking arround I found that I could get the [images sizes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53509/19326) and based on that do [some calculations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23226/alignment-and-scaling-of-nested-subfigures).

However doing this from hand seems tiresome (include the image in a savebox, get the widths, run them through formulas, insert them with scalefactors), and automateable. Is there a package to do so? (I am using floatrow, to place images side by side)

Comment: I edited my answer below to reflect the syntax of the latest `scalerel` package (1.5). When I wrote my original answer (not from my usual workplace), I apparently had an older version. The type of nesting I did in my `\sbox` syntax no longer worked. I have revised my answer to reflect this, and the fact that you didn't complain about it must mean you have an older version too. Please update to V1.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without addressing the specifics of floatrow, about which I know nothing, your problem has two components:  scaling the figures to the same height, and scaling the overall width to some dimension, such as `\textwidth`.  This MWE shows how to do both, using the `scalerel` package to match the height of one object to the next (while preserving the aspect ratio).  Then, I do a scale on the result to match the width to, in this case, `\textwidth`.

Where my figures are composed of `\rule`s, yours would be composed of `tikz` images.  Note also that `\scalerel` assumes its arguments are in math mode, and so I include the math delimiters to, in essence, get out of math mode.

I placed all the figures side-by-side into a single box `\x`.  However, if your requirements (for captioning, etc.) required you to keep the images as separate entities, `\scalerel*{$\figa$}{$\figd$}` would be the command to create a version of just `\figa` scaled to the size of `\figd`.  You of course, would still have to `\scalebox` it by a factor of `\scaleratio` to get it to the desired final size (I show this case as my final example).

EDITED to be compatible with latest package (scalerel V1.5)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\stacktype{L}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\def\figa{\color{blue}\rule{.5in}{.7in}}
\def\figb{\color{red}\rule{.7in}{.3in}}
\def\figc{\color{green}\rule{.4in}{.5in}}
\def\figd{\color{black}\rule{1.in}{.8in}}

Figures as is:

\figa\figb\figc\figd

figures scaled to height of figd

\newsavebox\x
\sbox\x{\scalerel{$\figc$}{$\figd$}}
\sbox\x{\scalerel{$\figb$}{\usebox{\x}}}
\sbox\x{\scalerel{$\figa$}{\usebox{\x}}}
\usebox{\x}

textwidth rule

\rule[1ex]{\textwidth}{.1ex}


figures scaled to textwidth in one box

\newcount\figwidthc
\newcount\textwidthc
\figwidthc=\wd\x
\textwidthc=\textwidth
\FPdiv\scaleratio{\the\textwidthc}{\the\figwidthc}
\scalebox{\scaleratio}{\usebox{\x}}

individual figures scaled to textwidth

\stackunder{\scalebox{\scaleratio}{\scalerel*{$\figa$}{$\figd$}}}{(a)}%
\stackunder{\scalebox{\scaleratio}{\scalerel*{$\figb$}{$\figd$}}}{(b)}%
\stackunder{\scalebox{\scaleratio}{\scalerel*{$\figc$}{$\figd$}}}{(c)}%
\stackunder{\scalebox{\scaleratio}{\figd}}{(d)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this solution, and will fiddle a bit with the code later on. I pretty much need what you explained in the last example. I wonder if there are some further optimizations: `1.`store the last figure (d) in a savebox, so it is not rendered every time I scale a, b and c `2.`Store a, b, c as well, since you use them twice, once to determine the overall width (2 times, onc e to compare the scaled to height figures to textwidth, once to actually draw them) `3.`can I somehow teach tex to calculate scaleratio automatically by simply putting only the last part (idividual figures) in a special env

Comment: Since only `3.` is an issue for me I will start a follow up question.

Comment: link to followup: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125738/19326 better automatization of the process

Answer (score 2):

Just scale the following pictures so that they have the same height as the first one and finally resize the row to be the width you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,etoolbox}

\newenvironment{imageRow}[1][\textwidth]
 {\center\firstimagetrue\def\rowwidth{#1}}
 {\resizebox{\rowwidth}{!}{\addimagerow}\endcenter}

\newif\iffirstimage
\newlength{\imageheight}
\newcommand{\addimage}[1]{%
  \sbox0{\includegraphics{#1}}%
  \iffirstimage
    \setlength{\imageheight}{\ht0}%
    \appto\addimagerow{\includegraphics{#1}}%
    \firstimagefalse
  \else
    \appto\addimagerow{\includegraphics[height=\imageheight]{#1}}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{imageRow}
\addimage{example-image.pdf}
\addimage{example-grid-100x100pt.pdf}
\addimage{example-image-golden.pdf}
\end{imageRow}

\begin{imageRow}[.7\textwidth]
\addimage{example-image.pdf}
\addimage{example-grid-100x100pt.pdf}
\addimage{example-image-golden.pdf}
\addimage{example-image-16x9.pdf}
\end{imageRow}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `center` environment is just for convenience.

This is not limited to `\includegraphics`; some changes may be needed to support other types of graphics such as TikZ pictures, but the idea is the same: so long that the images are vectorial, it's not a problem scaling them multiple times.

Comment: David Carlisle actually has a slightly simpler solution he gave in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18495414#18495414, just scale all images to an arbitrary height (but equal), then scale the row. This skips the need to get the height for the first image.

Comment: @ted I too thought of that, after posting my answer. I have a couple of ideas for improving it.