# LaTeX Scale Adjacent Terms' Grouping Symbols Together

Tags: scaling, brackets

I have two adjacent terms in a LaTeX equation, and I'd like the brackets around both to scale to the height of both terms.

For example `\left[ a \right] \left[ \frac{b}{c} \right]` generates:

[image: \left[ a \right] \left[ \frac{b}{c} \right]]

I'd like all four brackets to both be the same height.

Comment: `\biggl[a\biggr]\biggl[\dfrac{b}{c}\biggr]`

Comment: Take a look at the `scalerel` package, I had a similar question and got this excellent answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125722/19326. (It was about Images), but if you look inside the `scalerel` documentation you will find it talking about symbol scaling too, right in teh beginning of chapter 2 and chapter 3. `\stretchrel` might be what you need. This is overkill if it is just for one occurence though.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, not as elegant as Werner's.

Comment: @ted, unfortunately, this formula is going in MathJax, which doesn't seem to support \usepackage{...}.  I ran into that problem earlier when trying to scale a summation.

Comment: @IanMallett "elegance" lies in the eye of the beholder :-) Anyway I wouldn't recommend using `\left`, `\right`, except perhaps in very, very few cases.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Aye; I mean simply that the dependence on the second term is made obvious this way, as opposed to just scaling them to match.  What would you suggest instead?  The terms I replaced to get my toy example above are actually rather large in real life.

Comment: @IanMallett for regular (i.e., not too large expressions) I prefer the `\big...` family of commands, since the spacing around them is more consistent than using `\left`, `\right`. If your actual expressions are too big, then perhaps this is one of those very few cases in which the `\left`, `\right` construct is really needed.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: are there any other reasons besides the "consistent spacing" against `\left`/`\right`?

Comment: @ted spacing is the main reason. Another inconvenience is that if `\left`, `\right` is to be used and a change of line is involved in-between, one has to balance using `\right.` `\left.` and possibly make additional adjustment with phantoms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you could use

[image]

```
\left[\vphantom{\frac{b}{c}}a\right] \left[\frac{b}{c}\right]
```

using `\vphantom` to obtain the appropriate height of something without introducing an unnecessary width insertion. Alternatively, use fixed-sized scaled delimiters using "big"-variants. From the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) [user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) (section **4.14.1 Delimiter sizes**, p 15):

[image]