# Expansion for Macro to pass to scaleBox

Tags: tikz-pgf, expansion

I am trying to calculate some width in a macro and use the macro for `scalebox`. However I get a flood of errors when I try to pass the macro to scalebox.

MinimalExample:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}

\newcounter{Counter}
\setcounter{Counter}{1}

\newcommand{\testOk}{1}
\newcommand{\testFail}{
 \theCounter
 \stepcounter{Counter}
}


\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
  \testFail %ok
  \scalebox{\testFail}{a} %ok
  \scalebox{\testFail}{a} %fails
\end{document}
```

**Update**

Since I want to actually use scalebox transparently in a new environment I decided to try something along the lines pointed at by Steven B. Segletes. Redefining the macro to do first the macroexpansion and then call the underlying macro with the value. I tried:

```
\newenvironment{imageRow}{
 \begingroup\imageRow@reset
 \LetLtxMacro{\oldScalebox}{\scalebox}
 \renewcommand{\scalebox}[2]{
    \edef\tmpValue{##1}
    \oldScalebox{\tmpValue}{##2}
 }
}{
 \imageRow@complete\endgroup
}
```

However I keep getting 'missing endcsname' errors. (And a flood following that).

If it matters here is the function I am currently trying to pass as first argument:

```
\newcommand{\getIt}{%
    \stepcounter{imageRow@getCount}%
    %   
    \expandafter\ifx\csname imageRow@scale@Image@\theimageRow@rowCount @\alph{imageRow@getCount}\endcsname\relax
        1%
        \PackageWarning{imageRow}{Return to get correct scaling factors.}%
    \else
        \csname imageRow@scale@Image@\theimageRow@rowCount @\alph{imageRow@getCount}\endcsname\relax
    \fi
}
```

Comment: `\scalebox` needs a number but you have passed it instructions to typeset a counter and then do some arithmetic to add 1 and assign that value to a counter, that is never going to work, you need to do the arithmetic fist then pass in the value.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I am trying to write a small package to solve my old problem http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125722/19326. The idea is to automatically do some calculation and retireve the result to pass it to a scaling package like `scalebox` or `adjustbox`. I need csname for the retrival.

Comment: yes but as Steven shows below you need to pass the _result_ not instructions to execute some arithmetic and assignments. internally it is `count@=#1` which is fine if `#1` is a number but if you pass it `\the\mycount\relax \advance\mycount by 1 ` then it doesn't work.

Comment: Telling what you'd like to achieve would be a big step towards a solution.

Comment: I think your update suffers the same as your original.  That is, argument #1 has more than just a number... it has operations.  Using the `\edef` in your revised `\scalebox` will not remedy that.  Therefore, you still end up passing operations to `\oldscalebox`.

Comment: The update code is missing loads of `%` from ends of lines, and if I understand you correctly you are passing tokens including   `\setcounter` and `\PackageWarning` into the first argument which will put them in an `\edef` those commands can not possibly work in that context. The first argument of `\scalebox` is already expanded by `\scalebox` anything that you could put in an `\edef` can be passed as the argument to `\scalebox` so your redefinition does not do anything other than add spaces to the output.

Comment: @egreg: I am trying to wrap tex.stackexchange.com/a/125722/19326 into a package. The idea is to have an environment where I can do `\addImage{someCode}` to add an image and `\getScale` to get the factor by which the image should be scaled so that all pictures fill the row, and have equal height while keeping aspect ratios. I would like these two command so `adjustbox` `scalbox` or `tikzscale` can be used, depending on the situation. Take a look at https://github.com/coderinside/imageRow tp see what I got so far.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think I still have to get my head around tex, I am thinking a little bit in c-style here so to me `int func{return 2;}` and `int func{int i=getOneSomehow(); return i+1;}` are equal in the outcome of the program.

Comment: So is there someway that i can take an arbitrary defined command, execute it once and store its return in a way that it is save to pass to scalebox?

Comment: @ted tex is a macro expansion language so more like the c pre-processor than C, the analogy is not putttting a function there that returns an integer its like, in fact _is_ putting a macro their that inlines the body of the function, That wouldn't work in c either in general

Comment: @DavidCarlisle regarding the missing `%`, I tried it out, the `%` is the minimum amount to have no extrawhitespace in the output. If I do `\getIt\getIt` I get two numbers with no space in between, e.g. `1.2349.034` (notice the second decimal dot, with space it would be `1.234 9.034`)

Comment: @ted there is no _return_ it os a macro language not a functional language, if you macro leaves a value in a register or another macro, then you can pass in that result, but in general there is no result or return from an arbitrary macro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18436/discussion-between-ted-and-david-carlisle).

Comment: @ted your redefinition of scalebox (if it deosn't die in the edef would add 2 spaces before the scaled text and one space after

Comment: @ted I added an answer to the question you linked.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce `\tfscalebox`, so that the counter indexing occurs outside of the `\scalebox` argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}

\newcounter{Counter}
\setcounter{Counter}{1}

\newcommand{\testOk}{1}

\newcommand\tfscalebox[1]{\scalebox{\arabic{Counter}}{#1}\stepcounter{Counter}}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
  \tfscalebox{a} %ok
  \tfscalebox{a} %ok
  \tfscalebox{a} %ok
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the macro to perform a test before deciding to either output the `\scalebox` or increment `Counter`, then you could always pass a secondary argument to the macro  on which to test. Below, I do it as an optional argument `[F]` to decrement the scale:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\newcounter{Counter}
\setcounter{Counter}{1}
\newcommand\tfscalebox[2][T]{\scalebox{\arabic{Counter}}{#2}%
  \if#1F\addtocounter{Counter}{-1}\else\stepcounter{Counter}\fi%
  \if0\arabic{Counter}\stepcounter{Counter}\fi}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
  \tfscalebox{a} %ok
  \tfscalebox{b} %ok
  \tfscalebox{c} %ok
  \tfscalebox[F]{d} %ok
  \tfscalebox[F]{e} %ok
  \tfscalebox{a} %ok
  \tfscalebox[F]{e} %ok
  \tfscalebox[F]{e} %ok
  \tfscalebox[F]{e} %ok
  \tfscalebox[F]{e} %ok
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: WHile this is going the right way, I updated my anwser (see update), basically I try to go with your solution of evaluating my function and then passing the value to scalebox.